# Firebase function linkAndRetrieveDataWithCredential doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

To link an anonymous user to a newly-created user via email&pass I use the following function `linkAndRetrieveDataWithCredential`

For some reason I get the following error:

```
__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_12_firebase_app___default.a.auth(...).currentUser.linkAndRetrieveDataWithCredential is not a function
```

The function is documented in the official Firebase documentation on how to link an anonymous user. 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth

background: I use React.js and hence install Firebase via NPM.

What am I doing wrong ?

My code:

```
//if the user is anonymous, then upgrade the anonymous user to be the email&pass user.

    //get the Credential object
    var credential = firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential(this.state.email, this.state.password);

    //get the Credential object
    firebase.auth().currentUser.linkAndRetrieveDataWithCredential(credential).then(function(usercred) {
      var user = usercred.user;
      console.log("Anonymous account successfully upgraded", user);
      //the user was created. redirect to Home page 

      window.location.assign("/");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the function was deprecated.

the right solution is documented here:
[Firebase Convert Anonymous User Account to Permanent Account Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39088876/firebase-convert-anonymous-user-account-to-permanent-account-error)

```
    // (Anonymous user is signed in at that point.)

// 1. Create the email and password credential, to upgrade the
// anonymous user.
var credential = firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential(email, password);

// 2. Links the credential to the currently signed in user
// (the anonymous user).
firebase.auth().currentUser.linkWithCredential(credential).then(function(user) {
  console.log("Anonymous account successfully upgraded", user);
}, function(error) {
  console.log("Error upgrading anonymous account", error);
});
```